# Using PrincipalContext in the Global.asax to get AD information

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use the first code to then add it to the Global file (second code)? I can't seem to get it to work. I want to display string user from the second code in the global.asax.

Thanks,
EB

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    Session["Username"] = username;
}
```

Add This:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain.local"))
{
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` in place of the username in the second snippet?  *Why* are you storing the username in the session?  The `HttpContext.User` property tells you who the user is.

Comment: Couple things I am wanting to do. Currently I am displaying the AD full username in the layout page using a session variable from the controller page. This works fine. My goal is to use a @if on some views to only display some information if the username is x. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make some sense, but it doesn't answer Amy's question as far as I can see. I don't see why you need the session

Answer (score 1):

You can use `User.Identity.Name` both in Controller and Global.asax.cs.
This User comes from Base Controller Class which in inherited by your custom controller.

If you want to get names in your plain class files you can use these:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

In layout I am using this:

```
 <a href="#" id="userRole">
                            <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size:14px;"></i> @Business.FindPersonByMSID(User.Identity.Name.Substring(3))

                        </a>
```

You can use

`@if(User.Identity.Name)` in .cshtml anywhere.

Business.FindPersonByMSID is a static method in my Business class I am using to get the Full name of the person by his MSID or NTID .

You did not ask for below code but it will give you full view of what I am doing.

```
public static string FindPersonByMSID(string msid)
        {
            string displayName = "";
            if (msid.Trim() != "")
            {
                DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
                searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={0}))", msid);

                SearchResult allResults;
                allResults = searcher.FindOne();
                DirectoryEntry deMembershipUser = allResults.GetDirectoryEntry();
                deMembershipUser.RefreshCache();
                displayName = (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["displayname"].Value;
            }
            return displayName;
        }
```